# Unable to resolve "Error: Git server extension is unavailable." (Google Notebooks)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-notebook

After creating a new notebook instance in the last few days there is an internal error relating to the Git server extension when opened:

> Internal Error:
>
> Fail to get the server root path. Error: Git server extension is unavailable. Please ensure you have installed the JupyterLab Git server extension by running: pip install --upgrade jupyterlab-git. To confirm that the server extension is installed, run: jupyter serverextension list.

This means I can't use the Git clone button which returns:

> Clone failed:
>
> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Has this been occurring for others? I tried the `pip install --upgrade jupyterlab-git` as suggested but that didn't seem to fix anything. Below is my notebook instance setup (if not specified it is the default):

> Region: us-west1 (Oregon)
>
> Zone: us-west1-a
>
> Environment: TensorFlow Enterprise 2.1 (with Intel® MKL-DNN/MKL and CUDA 10.1)
>
> Machine type: n1-standard-4 (4vCPUs, 15 GB RAM)
>
> GPU type: NVIDIA Tesla T4
>
> Number of GPUs: 1
>
> ✓ Install NVIDA GPU driver automatically for me

I'm still quite new with both Google Cloud and this is my first Stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and is solved in in the newly released images ([m47](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/release-notes)).