# Unable to resolve “Error: Git server extension is unavailable.” for Pytorch jupyter notebook

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

After creating a new notebook instance(VM type: Pytorch 1.4), there is an internal error relating to the Git server extension when opened:

```
Internal Error:

Fail to get the server root path. Error: Git server extension is unavailable. Please ensure you have installed the JupyterLab Git server extension by running: pip install --upgrade jupyterlab-git. To confirm that the server extension is installed, run: jupyter serverextension list.
```

This means I can't use the Git clone button which returns:

```
Clone failed:

JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

When i tried the command, *jupyter serverextension list*, i found that git extension is disabled.

```
 jupyterlab_git disabled
    - Validating...
      jupyterlab_git 0.10.1 OK
```

I tried both 'jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyterlab_git --sys-prefix' and 'pip install --upgrade jupyterlab-git' as suggested but that didn't seem to fix anything. Below is my notebook instance setup (if not specified it is the default):

```
Region: us-west1 (Oregon)

Zone: us-west1-a

Environment: PyTorch 1.4 (with Intel® MKL-DNN/MKL and CUDA 10.1)

Machine type: n1-standard-4 (4vCPUs, 15 GB RAM)

GPU type: NVIDIA Tesla T4

Number of GPUs: 1

✓ Install NVIDA GPU driver automatically for me
```

Has this been occurring for others? I saw a similar post for TensorFlow VM([Unable to resolve "Error: Git server extension is unavailable." (Google Notebooks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61752903/unable-to-resolve-error-git-server-extension-is-unavailable-google-notebook)) and wondering if it is the same scenario?

Comment: Does the issue still relevant for you and the solution being posted worked as well?

Comment: There are plenty of Deep Learning VM Images introduced since the question was initially created.

Answer (score 0):

As the link [1], this is a known issue and is solved in the newly released images (m47) [2]:

[1] [Unable to resolve "Error: Git server extension is unavailable." (Google Notebooks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61752903/unable-to-resolve-error-git-server-extension-is-unavailable-google-notebook)

[2] https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/release-notes

Comment: In link[2], release note for m47 says "Fixed a git extensions plugin issue in TensorFlow 2 images.". It seems to be only fixed for TF images. BTW, i am using Pytorch image.

Comment: I think we fix it in Base, which includes PyTorch. Did you try the new image and test it?